# SwiftUI/Combine no updates to @ObservedObject from @Published

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, observedobject

I have a logon screen followed by an overview screen. When the user is successful at logon, the logon response sends back a list of items, which I want to display on the subsequent overview screen.

I can see the response being successfully mapped but the overview view is not receiving any update to the @ObservedObject. I could be missing something obvious but I've been through a bunch of articles and haven't managed to get anything working. Any help appreciated!

**Logon view**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LogonView: View {

    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var inputError: Bool = false
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State private var loading: Bool? = false
    @State private var helpShown: Bool = false
    @State private var successful: Bool = false


    //MARK:- UIView
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                VStack {
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .disabled(loading! ? true : false)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 2.0)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(!inputError ? Color("SharesaveLightGrey") : Color("SharesaveError"))
                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                }.padding(.top, 80)


                VStack {
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .disabled(loading! ? true : false)
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 2.0)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(!inputError ? Color("SharesaveLightGrey") : Color("SharesaveError"))
                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                }.padding(.top, 40)



                if (inputError) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(errorMessage)
                            .padding(.top)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("SharesaveError"))
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .font(.footnote)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }


                SharesaveButton(action: {self.submit(user: self.username, pass: self.password)},
                       label: "Log on",
                       loading: $loading,
                       style: .primary)
                    .padding(.top, 40)
                .animation(.interactiveSpring())


                NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView(), isActive: $successful) {
                    Text("")
                }

                Spacer()

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hello.")
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: { self.helpShown = true }) {
                     Text("Need help?").foregroundColor(.gray)
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $helpShown) {
                    SafariView( url: URL(string: "http://google.com")! )
            }

        }
    }


    //MARK:- Functions
    private func submit(user: String, pass: String) {

        loading = true
        inputError = false
        let resultsVM = ResultsViewModel()

        resultsVM.getGrants(user: user, pass: pass,

        successful: { response in
            self.loading = false
            if ((response) != nil) { self.successful = true }
        },

        error: { error in
            self.inputError = true
            self.loading = false
            self.successful = false
            switch error {
            case 401:
                self.errorMessage = "Your credentials were incorrect"
            default:
                self.errorMessage = "Something went wrong, please try again"
            }
        },

        failure: { fail in
            self.inputError = true
            self.loading = false
            self.successful = false
            self.errorMessage = "Check your internet connection"
        })
    }
}
```

**Results View Model**

```
import Foundation
import Moya
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ResultsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var results: Results = Results()

    func getGrants(
        user: String,
        pass: String,
        successful successCallback: @escaping (Results?) -> Void,
        error errorCallback: @escaping (Int) -> Void,
        failure failureCallback: @escaping (MoyaError?) -> Void
        )
    {
        let provider = MoyaProvider<sharesaveAPI>()

        provider.request(.getSharesave(username: user, password: pass)) { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success(let value):
                do {
                    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: value.data)
                    self.results = data
                    successCallback(data)

                } catch {
                    let errorCode = value.statusCode
                    errorCallback(errorCode)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                failureCallback(error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Overview View**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct OverviewView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultsViewModel = ResultsViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        let text = "\(self.viewModel.results.market?.sharePrice ?? 0.00)"

        return List {
            Text(text)
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You submitted request to one instance of `ResultsViewModel`

```
private func submit(user: String, pass: String) {

    loading = true
    inputError = false
    let resultsVM = ResultsViewModel() // << here
```

by try to read data from another instance of `ResultsViewModel`

```
struct OverviewView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultsViewModel = ResultsViewModel() // << here
```

but it must be *the one* instance, so modify as follows

1) In `OverviewView`

```
struct OverviewView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultsViewModel // expects injection
```

2) In `LogonView`

```
struct LogonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var resultsViewModel = ResultsViewModel() // created once
```

and inject same instance for `OverviewView`

```
NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView(viewModel: self.resultsViewModel), isActive: $successful) {
    Text("")
}
```

and in submit

```
    private func submit(user: String, pass: String) {

        loading = true
        inputError = false
        let resultsVM = self.resultsViewModel // use created
```

Comment: is there a way to do this other than injecting it the next view? The destination may be variable from LogonView (eg may go via one or two more views before landing on LogonView)

Answer (score 0):

Please try after change in initialise `OverviewView` like below in `NavigationLink`

```
NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView(viewModel: self.resultsVM),
                                         isActive: $successful) {
       Text("")
}
```

OR

pass `results` in `OverviewView` as argument like below

```
NavigationLink(destination: OverviewView(results: self.resultsVM.results),
                                         isActive: $successful) {
       Text("")
}
.....
struct OverviewView: View {
    let results: Results
    var body: some View {
        let text = "\(self.results.market?.sharePrice ?? 0.00)"
        return List {
           Text(text)
        }           
    }
}
```